security log of all account activity
I need to use my accounts (stackoverflow, quora, reddit, hackernews, standardnotes, amplenotes, lu.ma, afraidorg, etc, etc) on a public computer.
Therefore I need someone/something to monitor account usage to that extent possible, in case Mallory/Yves/Oscar does something with the accounts.
Requirement:

Obviously the attacker must not be able to delete the logs after hacking 'everything'.
Secure (please no fishy business models.. simple ones are great).
Free.

Bonus (in order):

covers as many applications as possible including Gmail, Zoho, Microsoft, not just Stackoverflow (or Quora or AmpleNotes).
indicate what is logged vs what is leaky
save-in-cloud and log everything (to 3rd party [paid] storage?) such that when Mallory does All Your Content are belong to /dev/null, I still have everything, even if without one-click restore button
fully exportable
programmable such that non-common applications used by the user can be added  himself (or someone online has done it and he  copypaste-enter)
notify when something fishy is going on
good table for easy analysis
covers itself

